# Querying tables from metastore in Hive throwing error

Tags: hive, hiveql

when i tried to query metastore in hive i am getting below error.

```
hive> use mydb;
OK
Time taken: 0.052 seconds
hive> select * from DBS;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'DBS'
hive> select * from TBLS;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'TBLS'
```

i am using hadoop version : Hadoop 2.7.3.2.6.2.3-1

**Is this a access privilage issue?**

kindly share your suggestion

Comment: Try `show tables` after `use mydb`. If tables of your interest are listed then try `msck repair table dbs` (the same for the other one). Plus check if your tables are in `default` database

Comment: @serge_k: 
after show tables i am able to see all the table but i think
DBS and TBLS are metadata table in metastore. it is not showing in the list.please help me to fix the error Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
select * from hive.TBLS;
```

Regarding your question from comments:

```
use hive;
show tables;
```

Also, you can find useful [this link](https://analyticsanvil.wordpress.com/2016/08/21/useful-queries-for-the-hive-metastore/).